# Conflict between my UploadActivity and Lollipop version

Tags: java, android, adapter

My Upload activity select images from gallery and upload it.

I Open my upload Activity from another one, when i open it in Marshmallow it's worked great, but when I open it from Lollipop, it's take too much time to open.

what's wrong with my code, that make this conflict?

```
    public class UploadActivity extends Activity {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = ImagesForAds.class.getSimpleName();

    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    ArrayList<String> IPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static Uri uri;
    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();
        final Button uploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadDONE);
        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = arrPath[i];
                        IPath.add(selectImages);
                    }
                }

                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select at least one image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);

                    Intent intentMessage = new Intent(UploadActivity.this,
                            ImagesForAds.class);
                    intentMessage.putStringArrayListExtra("IMAGE", IPath);
                    startActivity(intentMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, ImagesForAds.class);
        UploadActivity.this.finish();
        startActivity(i);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably marshmallow phone you are using has a lot more images in mediastore, thats why your activity starts slowly.

That said, there are general perfomance issues in your code:

- you use method moveToPosition for every row in your cursor, better use moveToFirst and moveToNext methods in a loop.
- you are loading all thumbnails to the memory at activity start. This can take a long time when there are many images, also you can easily run out of memory. Better load these tumbnails in your adapter as needed.

Better yet, make your adapter inherit from CursorAdapter, this should give you best startup time.

Comment: Thanks, but is cursorAdapter work with recycleview ? 
and how i can load tumbnails in adapter as needed ? please you may show me a sample ?